# Dump SQL as plain text using PHP

Tags: mysql, sql, php

Basically what I need to do is dump a SQL database in plain text using PHP. Just like phpMyAdmin does when you choose not to get a file while exporting.

This way I can send it via mail and reinsert it later using a SQL query.

Is this even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it helps

```
<?php

$dbhost   = "HOSTNAME";
$dbuser   = "USERNAME";
$dbpwd    = "PASSWORD";
$dbname   = "DATABASENAME";

$dumpfile = $dbname . "_" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".sql";
passthru("/usr/bin/mysqldump --opt --host=$dbhost --user=$dbuser
--password=$dbpwd $dbname > $dumpfile");

// report - disable with // if not needed
// must look like "-- Dump completed on ..." 

echo "$dumpfile "; passthru("tail -1 $dumpfile");
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

This is both possible and very easy .. "dumping" SQL data in such a way is really not any different than just querying it and writing the queries.  If you're running on a linux server, I would suggest you just use `mysqldump` instead since it's designed specifically for that.  You can forgo php altogether, but if you want, you can even run the `mysqldump` command from php using something like `exec` and still email the results with php.

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
define("SITE_DB_USERNAME", "$db_user");
define("SITE_DB_PASSWORD", "$db_pass");
define("SITE_DB_NAME", "$db");

system(" mysql -u".SITE_DB_USERNAME." -p".SITE_DB_PASSWORD." -hlocalhost ".SITE_DB_NAME." > file.txt );
```

thanks